# C++: How do I access a variable from another class definition

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a little pokemon game, that obviously includes attacking another pokemon. Don't worry about Type; that's just a ENUM.

Currently not working: The _reciever's health doesn't get changed, there are no errors

my current not working code:

```
class Pokemon
    {
    public:
        string Name;
        Type Type;
        int Health;

        Pokemon(string _name, Pokemons::Type _type, int _health)
        {
            Name = _name;
            Type = _type;
            Health = _health;
        }

        bool checkHealth()
        {
            if (Health <= 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        void updateHealth(char _operator, int _amount)
        {
            switch (_operator)
            {
            case '+':
                Health = Health + _amount;
                break;
            case '-':
                Health = Health - _amount;
                break;
            case '*':
                Health = Health * _amount;
                break;
            case '/':
                Health = Health / _amount;
                break;
            }
        }

        void attackEnemy(Pokemon _reciever)
        {
            _reciever.Health = _reciever.Health - 5;
        }

    };
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pokemon.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Pokemons;

int main()
{
    Pokemon Charmender("Charmender", Fire, 45);
    Pokemon Bulbasaur("Bulbasaur", Water, 50);

    while (true) {
        Charmender.attackEnemy(Bulbasaur);
        cout << Bulbasaur.Health << endl;
    }
}
```

ps: this is my first ever stackoverflow question, do let me know if I missed something

Comment: `void attackEnemy(Pokemon _reciever)` -- You are passing `_reciever` by value, meaning that the `attackEnemy` function is working on a local copy that goes up in smoke as soon as that function returns.  In other words, there is no effect on `Bulbasaur` in the `main` function.  But this should be covered in any good C++ book, right at the chapters that discuss passing parameters.

Comment: Ah yes Paul is right - the simple fix is to change `Pokemon _receiver` to `Pokemon& _receiver` (search for C++ references).

Comment: I would rather create a public method `takeDamage(float damage)`, this way each creature can compute how much damage it received (e.g. if you later implement some "armor" mechanic, then `takeDamage` would internall reduce the damage by some value before subtraction from health

Comment: Are you trying to learn C++ coming from a Java or a C# background?

Comment: Hi Sam, that is correct, I've been using C# for a while

Comment: @RickHuisman *I've been using C# for a while* -- That may explain why you made the mistake you made.  Passing parameters like this in C++ is vastly different than C#.  In C++, you must *explicitly* state you are passing the entity by reference (thus behavior similar to C#) -- it is not automatically assumed you want to do this.  Also, this indicates you're using C# as a model in writing C++ code.  Do not do this, as you can see for yourself the mess you get into trying to do line-by-line translations from C# (or any other language) to C++.

Comment: Hey, Paul and Tim. Your combined answer fixed the problem, how can I set it that that's the fix?

Comment: In that case, you will do yourself a huge, huge favor if you forget everything you know about C# while you're learning C++. C++ is not C# and works in fundamentally different ways, like this specific issue: in C++ all function parameters get passed by value. Assuming that something works in C++ because it looks almost exactly like something looks in C# will always end in tears.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll bear it in mind and great response time btw!

Comment: @RickHuisman -- FWIW, passing parameters will *always* trip up a beginner C++ coder that knows C# or Java, but didn't read up carefully on how C++ works when it comes to passing parameters.  And the same thing can be said vice-versa -- a C++ programmer who writes C# or Java code expecting the function to work on a local copy will also fail miserably.

Comment: Actually it's not that all parameters in C# get passed by reference. It's just that all objects in C# are actually pointers, and not real objects (Java works the same way). And the pointers get passed by value. The equivalent C++ code would also work exactly the same way.

Comment: Personally I subscribe to "you will do yourself a huge, huge favor if you forget everything you know about C#". RIght, back in my box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are accessing the other class member variables without problems, but your changes are not as intended because you are passing a copy of the object:

```
void attackEnemy(Pokemon _reciever)
        {
            _reciever.Health = _reciever.Health - 5;
        }
```

With this approach, `_receiver` goes away at the end of your method.
To get persistent changes, you can pass by reference:

```
void attackEnemy(Pokemon &_reciever)
        {
            _reciever.Health = _reciever.Health - 5;
        }
```